# How to sanitize an input command in shell script by blacklisting/whitelisting?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a very expanded source code. I added a number of new source files to different paths, and wrote a shell script to open all of my files  in a text editor.

I get an input from user to open files in his favourite code editor (gedit, geany, sublime, ...). For the sake of defensive programming, I would like to filter some commands like `rm` which can delete all my files instead of opening them!

My question is what is the best way to achieve this? If I want to blacklist or whitelist a set of commands, do I need to compare the input command against all of the commands in the blacklist/whitelist? Is there any shorter way?

Comment: Instead of filtering 'all the other' commands I'd rather not except anything other than `gedit, geany, sublime, ...`. So I'd go for a whitelist.

Comment: Not all commands, but commands like `rm`, `mv`, `cp`. My question is actually what if this list is a long list? Should I compare all of them one by one using an `if`?

Comment: Any such effort is doomed to fail. Much better to use best practices (such as source control) to be able to recover after a problem than to try to limit your own expressiveness to prevent it.

Comment: A `case` statement is a more appropriate tool than an `if`, for what very little good it'll do. You could also use an associative array, which blacklisted or whitelisted commands as keys.

Comment: You're not the first person to ask this, by the way, and I may have actually written a proof-of-concept implementation for the other one (with all the requisite warnings of just how bad an idea it was). You might try searching around in the pool of previously-answered questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a user to be able to edit files but not run other, arbitrary commands on them, do all of the following:

- Store the files under a user account the user doesn't have direct access to.
- Configure `/etc/sudoers` to allow that user to run only specifically whitelisted commands as an account able to read the file.
- Support only editors which have a restricted mode. By default, for instance, `vim` can be used to run arbitrary commands, but it has a (restricted) `rvim` alternative which doesn't allow privilege escalation.

Or do the sane thing, and use version control. :)

Comment: It is also interesting to jail users. [creating an SSH only shell in a chroot jail](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_ssh_only.html)

Comment: Yup. Doesn't really help here, since we want the user to be able to edit the same files we're trying to prevent them from deleting(!).

Comment: It's actually a very large repository. The source code itself is close 1GB! I can recover the files from remote repo, but navigating through all the paths and finding added files for new developers is not easy. So, I am looking for a safe and easy way to provide access to these files.

Comment: Have you considered hardlink trees, with the original/template under a top-level directory where developers' accounts lack `+x` permission?